# How to open qt5 designer in linux using terminal?

Tags: terminal, gui, user-interface

How to open qt5 designer in ubuntu
I installed it through the terminal using a command

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt5 qt5-designer
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this command you can run/open qt5-designer in ubuntu

```
>> qtchooser -run-tool=designer -qt=5
```